# How to enable javascript console on Android 4.2.2

Tags: javascript, android, debugging, samsung-mobile

I'm trying to enable the JavaScript Console to debug a webpage in the stock Android browser on a Samsung Galaxy S4 running 4.2.2.

On the S3 I just type in about:debug in the address bar and it comes up but it doesn't work on the S4, it seems to do an autocomplete for chrome://debug.

Firstly it would be great to know how to get the console open and secondly why would Chrome's autocomplete be coming up for the stock browser?

Thanks

Comment: Did you enable dev tools in the browser options?

Comment: This worked for me: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/android-browsers-aboutdebug-what-do-those-settings-do

Comment: The debug tools are available in the chrome://debug page tab, where typing about:debug sends you. (The page reads, "This webpage is not available") .  As soon as you navigate away or if you switch to a different open tab, they disappear, so the tool is not at all useful.  @Jonathan, you will have to provide more info.  Are you on an S4, 4.2.2?  What part of your provided link helped you?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Greg, I'm no longer working on that project or have access to an S4 but I never managed to get it working either.

Comment: @Greg, The link I shared worked to open a console on several of my Android devices, but, as you point out it isn't very helpful. Ultimately, I used Chrome desktop's remote debugging feature for one of my projects. https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging

Comment: Same problem here on Samsung S4 mini (Android 4.2.2).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to activate this console.

But I have used a tool that can allow you to remote debug any browser with limited changes to your web page (only add one script).
It is **VorlonJS** and you can find demo here: http://vorlonjs.com/#demo

Comment: The problem sometimes is, that you can't debug remote. :(

Comment: Vorlon is awesome + free!

Answer (score 0):

try this link [remote debugging chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging).
Well if are you developing on android greater than 4.0.3 you can type `adb logcat` and you would be able to catch your console.log or errors.
Or if you want chrome enables mobile screen to test the view.It depends if you are testing the functionality or the graphics