# How to view Javascript console of Stock Browser in Android Galaxy S4

Tags: javascript, android, debugging, android-4.2-jelly-bean, galaxy

I was following through the steps mentioned in the similar  [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20648387/how-to-enable-javascript-console-on-android-4-2-2) and was still unable to get the javascript console in Samsung Galaxy S4, running Jellybean version of Android 4.2.2.

Steps I have followed so far:

1. Entered the string `chrome://debug` in Stock browser's omni bar .
2. open context menu ->Settings -> Debug.
3. Make sure that Show `JavaScript Console` is checked.

Even after following the above steps, Javascript console is not showing up.

Can anybody help me, If I am missing anything.